# Render list after updating

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to add items from list allconfigurations to list currentconfigurations

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:outputText value="All Configurations:"/>
    <b:dataTable id="allConfigurations" var="rowItem" value="#{administratorManager.allConfigurations}" 
        paginated="true" searching="true" lang="true">
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rowItem.description}" />
        <b:dataTableColumn value="#{rowItem.description}" />
        <b:dataTableColumn label="Actions">

            <h:commandLink value="Add">        
                <f:ajax event="click" listener="# {administratorManager.addConfiguration(rowItem)}" 
                    render=":formId:result, allConfigurations, currentConfigurations"/>
            </h:commandLink>
        </b:dataTableColumn>
     </b:dataTable>

    <h:panelGroup id="result">
         <h:outputText value="#{administratorManager.currentConfigurations}" rendered="true" />

            #{administratorManager.currentConfigurations}
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

If i reload the page the items appear into the list.

ManagedBean:

```
@Named(value = "administratorManager")
@SessionScoped
public class AdministratorManager implements Serializable {
    ...
    public void addConfiguration(Configuration selectedConfiguration){
        logger.warning("I WAS EXECUTED, ADDCONFIGURATIONS");
        allConfigurations.remove(selectedConfiguration);
        currentConfigurations.add(selectedConfiguration);
        logger.warning(String.valueOf(currentConfigurations.size()));
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `:formId:allConfigurations`? in the `render` attribute?

Comment: Ye, not working

Comment: Weird... What you have is wrong, please create a [mcve] then. Cause is not visible  then. And btw, aren't you using BootsFaces instead of PrimeFaces?

Comment: The render selector cannot find the component thats the problem

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo

Comment: Which value of the render could not be found? When did you get this error?